# Using knex WITH statement with values

Tags: node.js, postgresql, common-table-expression, knex.js

Using Knex with a postgresql DB.  I am trying to build a query something like this:

```
with included(some_id) as (
VALUES(some_id1),(some_id2))
select a.somefield, b.somefield from mytable1 as a
join myothertable as b on b.id = a.id
join included i on a.some_id = i.some_id;
```

I am trying to do the WITH call like so:

```
q = knex.with('included', ['form_id'], knex.raw(`values ${inc}`));
```

inc is a string I build from another call that would look like this: (some_id1),(some_id2), ect

After updating knex, it removed the error but still gives bad sql.  The WITH call above gives the following.

with included(form_id) as (values (1083)) select *

There does not seem to be another way to use VALUES inside the WITH with knex other than raw.

Comment: Possible solution: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/716